# How to include "zero" / "0" results in COUNT aggregate?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I've just got myself a little bit stuck with some SQL. I don't think I can phrase the question brilliantly - so let me show you.

I have two tables, one called person, one called appointment. I'm trying to return the number of appointments a person has (including if they have zero). Appointment contains the `person_id` and there is a `person_id` per appointment. So `COUNT(person_id)` is a sensible approach.

The query:

```
SELECT person_id, COUNT(person_id) AS "number_of_appointments" 
FROM appointment 
GROUP BY person_id;
```

Will return correctly, the number of appointments a person_id has. However, a person who has 0 appointments isn't returned (obviously as they are not in that table).

Tweaking the statement to take person_id from the person table gives me something like:

```
SELECT person.person_id, COUNT(appointment.person_id) AS "number_of_appointments"
FROM appointment
JOIN person ON person.person_id = appointment.person_id
GROUP BY person.person_id;
```

This however, will still only return a person_id who has an appointment and not what I want which is a return with persons who have 0 appointments!

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What if I want to get zero | 0 as result on single table. I've vm_tool_licenses table and query is like below   select vm_tool_id, count(vm_tool_license_active) from vm_tool_licenses 
                                    group by vm_tool_license_active,vm_tool_id having vm_tool_license_active = false`

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You want an outer join for this (and you need to use person as the "driving" table)

```
SELECT person.person_id, COUNT(appointment.person_id) AS "number_of_appointments"
FROM person 
  LEFT JOIN appointment ON person.person_id = appointment.person_id
GROUP BY person.person_id;
```

The reason why this is working, is that the outer (left) join will return `NULL` for those persons that do not have an appointment. The aggregate function `count()` will not count `NULL` values and thus you'll not get a zero.

If you want to learn more about outer joins, here is a nice tutorial: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Using_Null

Comment: but what if some of the fields of the appointment are NOT NULL (in the table definition)?

Comment: @LiorYehezkely: "some of the columns" doesn't matter. The count() uses the join column. If that is not null, then there is an appointment which should be counted

Answer (score 24):

You must use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT person.person_id, COUNT(appointment.person_id) AS "number_of_appointments"
FROM person 
LEFT JOIN appointment ON person.person_id = appointment.person_id
GROUP BY person.person_id;
```

Comment: The GROUP BY seems like a typo in the original question since the table isn't included in the query.

Answer (score 7):

if you do the outer join (with the count), and then use this result as a sub-table, you can get 0 as expected (thanks to the nvl function)

Ex:

```
select P.person_id, nvl(A.nb_apptmts, 0) from 
(SELECT person.person_id
FROM person) P
LEFT JOIN 
(select person_id, count(*) as nb_apptmts
from appointment 
group by person_id) A
ON P.person_id = A.person_id
```

Answer (score 5):

USE join to get 0 count in the result using GROUP BY.

simply 'join' does Inner join in MS SQL so , Go for left or right join.

If the table which contains the primary key is mentioned first in the QUERY then use LEFT join else RIGHT join.

EG:

```
select WARDNO,count(WARDCODE) from MAIPADH 
right join  MSWARDH on MSWARDH.WARDNO= MAIPADH.WARDCODE
group by WARDNO
```

.

```
select WARDNO,count(WARDCODE) from MSWARDH
left join  MAIPADH on MSWARDH.WARDNO= MAIPADH.WARDCODE group by WARDNO
```

Take group by from the table which has Primary key and count from the another table which has actual entries/details.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with a LEFT JOIN is that if there are no appointments, it will still return one row with a null, which when aggregated by COUNT will become 1, and it will appear that the person has one appointment when actually they have none.  I think this will give the correct results:

```sql
SELECT person.person_id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM appointment WHERE person.person_id = appointment.person_id) AS 'Appointments'
FROM person;
```

Answer (score 4):

To change even less on your original query, you can turn your join into a `RIGHT` join

```
SELECT person.person_id, COUNT(appointment.person_id) AS "number_of_appointments"
FROM appointment
RIGHT JOIN person ON person.person_id = appointment.person_id
GROUP BY person.person_id;
```

This just builds on the selected answer, but as the outer join is in the `RIGHT` direction, only one word needs to be added and less changes. - Just remember that it's there and can sometimes make queries more readable and require less rebuilding.