# Group by breaks count when count = 0

Tags: mysql

I have searched through what appear to be relevant questions but am still unable to solve my issue.

```
SELECT c.name AS 'Computer', COUNT(h.hotfixid) AS '# Missing',
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(h.hotfixid) ='0' THEN 'Fully Patched'
    WHEN COUNT(h.hotfixid) BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN '1 - 4 Missing'
    WHEN COUNT(h.hotfixid) BETWEEN 5 AND 12 THEN '5 - 12 Missing'
    WHEN COUNT(h.hotfixid) >12 THEN 'Attention > 12 Missing' 
    END AS 'Status', 
c.os AS 'Operating System'
FROM hotfix h
LEFT JOIN computers c ON h.computerid=c.computerid
LEFT JOIN clients cl ON c.clientid=cl.clientid
WHERE h.Installed='0' AND h.Approved='1' AND c.clientid = '229'
GROUP BY c.name
```

The problem is that the above will not return anything that has a 0 or no records. The GROUP BY breaks it.

This query returns my expected result, but when I add GROUP BY to it no results are returned at all.

```
    SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(hotfixid) ='0' THEN 'Fully Patched'
    WHEN COUNT(hotfixid) BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN '1 - 4 Missing'
    WHEN COUNT(hotfixid) BETWEEN 5 AND 12 THEN '5 - 12 Missing'
    WHEN COUNT(hotfixid) >12 THEN 'Attention > 12 Missing'
    END AS 'Status'
FROM hotfix
WHERE computerid = '8176' AND hotfix.`approved` = '1' AND hotfix.`installed` = '0'
```

This query returns a 0, so I know I'm getting 0 and not a 'NULL'

```
SELECT computerid,
    COUNT(hotfixid) 
    FROM hotfix
    WHERE computerid = '8176' AND hotfix.`approved` = '1' AND hotfix.`installed` = '0'
```

Edit.

The hotfix table Info:

[image]

My expected output is to list by machines, their patching status, but the Fully Patched Status wont display:

[image: MySQL Yog output]

Thanks for any assistance.

Regards Peter.

Comment: Consider providing sample data set and with proper table definitions and also add your desired result set

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include "zero" / "0" results in COUNT aggregate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793057/how-to-include-zero-0-results-in-count-aggregate)

Comment: I think that's to be expected since the Grouping is being done on a field from another table. Which table is the one that will always have data?

Comment: Thanks @Phil, I have had a look at that link you posted, and changed my 'driving' table to computers and also changed the count from h.hotfixid to c.name. No difference in the result at all.

Comment: Hi @RMK thnaks, I'm not sure wha tyou mean by which table will always have data, all the tables used in the query always have data. Ahhh, I think I see what your getting at. I tried GROUP BY h.computerid as that's the same table that contains the count data and nothing changed in my results apart from a slight change in the order machines displayed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes more sense to have `computers` left join `hotfix`. And `c.os` is missing in `group by.`

```
SELECT c.name AS 'Computer', COUNT(h.hotfixid) AS '# Missing',
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(h.hotfixid) ='0' THEN 'Fully Patched'
    WHEN COUNT(h.hotfixid) BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN '1 - 4 Missing'
    WHEN COUNT(h.hotfixid) BETWEEN 5 AND 12 THEN '5 - 12 Missing'
    WHEN COUNT(h.hotfixid) >12 THEN 'Attention > 12 Missing' 
    END AS 'Status', 
c.os AS 'Operating System'
FROM computers c
LEFT OUTER JOIN hotfix h ON c.computerid=h.computerid AND h.Installed='0' AND h.Approved='1'
LEFT OUTER JOIN clients cl ON c.clientid=cl.clientid AND c.clientid = '229'
GROUP BY c.name, c.os
```

Comment: Hi @chianh, thanks. I ran that exactly as you show, no change in the result returned. Still no go.

Comment: Updated with join condition after on. Give me a sample of data if you can

Comment: Yeah, you got it now @chianh Thank you!