# Count with 0 results not appear

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, bdd

i have a question
I need this select give me the nº of counts group by contenedor

```
SELECT C.Contenedor, count(DC.Contenedor) as NUM
FROM contenedores AS C, det_contenedores as DC
WHERE C.Contenedor=DC.Contenedor
GROUP BY C.Contenedor
```

But only appear the "C.Contenedor" that have "count(DC.Contenedor)" > 0

The result is (for example):

```
A->3
B->7
D->6
```

I would like to have:

```
A->3
B->7
C->0
D->6
E->0
```

any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793057/how-to-include-zero-0-results-in-count-aggregate

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`:

```
SELECT C.Contenedor, count(DC.Contenedor) as NUM
FROM 
    contenedores AS C 
    LEFT JOIN det_contenedores as DC
        ON C.Contenedor=DC.Contenedor
GROUP BY C.Contenedor
```

Comment: mmmm oki! but if i want to do a select that do the same but searching by one Contenedor?? Something like this
`SELECT C.Contenedor, count(DC.Contenedor) as NUM
FROM 
    contenedores AS C 
    LEFT JOIN det_contenedores as DC
        ON C.Contenedor=DC.Contenedor and C.Contenedor = 3
GROUP BY C.Contenedor`
why dont appear CONTENEDOR 3--->0 (count)