# Zero if no value returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT  
    f.name, 
    COUNT(distinct(p.id))
FROM 
    problems p INNER JOIN problem_list pl on p.problem_list_id = pl.id 
    FULL OUTER JOIN facilities f on f.id = p.facility
WHERE  
    p.problem_list_id = '100' 
    AND f.name in ('CRJ','TVRJ','WRJ')
GROUP BY
    f.name
ORDER BY
    f.name
```

When this query is run, sometimes one of the `facilities` does not return a result. In that case, I'd still like my result set to show that facility, but return a 0.

For example:

```
CRJ       |          0|
TVRJ      |         12|
WRJ       |          2|
```

I've tried to use `coalesce`, and adjusting my joins on the `facility` table, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include "zero" / "0" results in COUNT aggregate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793057/how-to-include-zero-0-results-in-count-aggregate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that a `FULL JOIN` is needed, just a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  
    f.name, 
    ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT p.id),0) N
FROM 
    facilities f 
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * 
                FROM problems
                WHERE problem_list_id = '100') p 
        ON f.id = p.facility
    LEFT JOIN problem_list pl 
        ON p.problem_list_id = pl.id 
WHERE  
    f.name in ('CRJ','TVRJ','WRJ')
GROUP BY
    f.name
ORDER BY
    f.name;
```

Comment: Why the need for the embedded query?

Comment: @FrumRoll It's exactly the same as using that filter as a join condition. I prefer this way of writing it because it's more clear (to me) that I'm filtering some rows

Answer (score 1):

Your original query started with problems, if you want to include facilities that haven't had problems you likely want to start with facilities.

```
SELECT f.name, ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT p.id), 0)
FROM facilities f
LEFT JOIN problems p ON p.facility = f.id AND p.problem_list_id = '100'
LEFT JOIN problem_list pl ON pl.id = p.problem_list_id
WHERE f.name in ('CRJ', 'TVRJ', 'WRJ')
GROUP BY f.name
ORDER BY f.name
```