# How to include 0 results in COUNT()

Tags: sql-server

I have 1 table containing ticket information, and a second with knowledge article information.
The tickets can be linked to the appropriate knowledge article.

In the ticket table (IncidentsM1) is a column CBA_KPF_ID which will either contain an article ID or a NULL.

I need to find out how many times each article was linked even if it's 0.

Tables (redacted):

- INCIDENTSM1 - Ticket table

  - INCIDENT_ID - Ticket ID
  - CBA_KPF_ID - Article ID
- KMDOCUMENTM1 - Article table

  - ID - Article ID

If I use the following code, I get the number of links except for those with 0 links:

```
SELECT KM1.ID, COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM INCIDENTSM1 AS SD LEFT JOIN KMDOCUMENTM1 AS KM1 ON SD.CBA_KPF_ID=KM1.ID
GROUP BY KM1.ID
```

One of the results is an ID value of NULL with the count of tickets which haven't linked to an article.

If I use the following (from other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793057/how-to-include-zero-0-results-in-count-aggregate)) code, I get a list of articles with the count either being 1 or 0 and article IDs appearing in multiple rows:

```
SELECT SD.CBA_KPF_ID, ISNULL(KM."Count", 0) FROM
(SELECT CBA_KPF_ID FROM INCIDENTSM1) SD
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID, count(ID) as "Count" FROM KMDOCUMENTM1 GROUP BY ID) KM
ON SD.CBA_KPF_ID=KM.ID
ORDER BY "Count" DESC
```

Is it possible to get the list of articles and how many times they were linked even if the number is 0?

EDIT:

I've tried both below answers, but they're either failing to group by ID or still not showing 0 values.

I just tried to generate the list without 0 values, then union a table with all the IDs not in the first statement:

```
(SELECT KM1.ID, COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM INCIDENTSM1 AS SD LEFT JOIN KMDOCUMENTM1 AS KM1 ON SD.CBA_KPF_ID=KM1.ID
GROUP BY KM1.ID)

UNION

SELECT KM.ID, 0
FROM KMDOCUMENTM1 AS KM

WHERE KM.ID NOT IN (
SELECT A.ID FROM
(SELECT KM1.ID, COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM INCIDENTSM1 AS SD LEFT JOIN KMDOCUMENTM1 AS KM1 ON SD.CBA_KPF_ID=KM1.ID GROUP BY KM1.ID) A
)
ORDER BY "Count" DESC
```

Problem here is everything below the UNION seems not to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following tables:

```
DECLARE @DataSource01 TABLE
(
    [ID] TINYINT
   ,[RefID] TINYINT
);

DECLARE @DataSource02 TABLE
(
    [RefID] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource01 ([ID], [RefID])
VALUES (1, 1)
      ,(1, 2)
      ,(1, 3)
      ,(2, NULL)
      ,(2, NULL)
      ,(3, 1)
      ,(3, 2)
      ,(3, NULL);

INSERT INTO @DataSource02 ([RefID])
VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

The data is:

```
SELECT *
FROM @DataSource01 DS1
LEFT JOIN @DataSource02 DS2
    ON DS1.[RefID] = DS2.[RefID];
```

[image]

So, I guess you need count of 3 for record 1, count of 0 for record 2, and count of 2 for record 3:

```
SELECT DS1.[ID]
      ,SUM(IIF(DS2.[RefID] IS NULL, 0, 1))
FROM @DataSource01 DS1
LEFT JOIN @DataSource02 DS2
    ON DS1.[RefID] = DS2.[RefID]
GROUP BY DS1.[ID]
```

[image]

Note, if [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) function is not supported in your SQL Server verstion, you can change it with `CASE WHEN` expresion.

Comment: Tried this, but still not getting any 0 values returned.
Just updated the question with another attempt.

Comment: Could you show me some sample data (you can use the table I have created) and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT KM1.ID,IFF(COUNT(*) is null,0,1) AS "Count"
FROM INCIDENTSM1 AS SD LEFT JOIN KMDOCUMENTM1 AS KM1 ON SD.CBA_KPF_ID=KM1.ID
GROUP BY KM1.ID
```

Comment: The IDs aren't being counted in this query. I'm getting the same number of rows as there are linked articles, but the counter is on 1 for each.

Comment: I think you mean to say IIF(COUNT(*) is null, 0, COUNT(*)), but that gives me exactly the same results as the first snippet of code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

if you count the non-null left hand side it should count rows, and if you count the right hand side it should only count matches

```
SELECT KM1.ID, COUNT(SD.CBA) AS CountAll, COUNT(KM1.ID) AS "CountMatches"
FROM INCIDENTSM1 AS SD LEFT JOIN KMDOCUMENTM1 AS KM1 ON SD.CBA_KPF_ID=KM1.ID
GROUP BY KM1.ID
```