# How to include zero-count results in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, outer-join

I have these two tables:

Operators:

```
Id Nome
--+----
 1 JDOE
 2 RROE
 3 MMOE
```

Calls:

```
Id CallDate OpId
--+--------+----
 1 20161228    2
 2 20161228    3
 3 20161228    2
 4 20161228    3
 5 20170104    1
 6 20170104    2
 7 20170104    1
```

And this query:

```
SELECT Operators.id, Operators.Nome, Count(Calls.OpId) AS CountCalls
FROM Operators LEFT JOIN Calls ON Operators.id = Calls.OpId
GROUP BY Calls.CallDate, Operators.id, Operators.Nome
HAVING Calls.CallDate=20170104;
```

Which returns:

```
Id Nome CountCalls
--+----+----------
 1 JDOE          2
 2 RROE          1
```

How can I make it return this, instead?

```
Id Nome CountCalls
--+----+----------
 1 JDOE          2
 2 RROE          1
 3 MMOE          0
```

That is, how to include in any query also the zero results from main table which has no occurrence in left joined table, at least in the data slice defined by the query filtering criteria?

This is Access 2013.

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14793090/3718031) but couldn't see how it is different from what I'm doing.

Comment: Do not reference any LEFT JOINed table column in WHERE clause predicates disallowing NULL value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you have a reference to `Calls.CallDate` in your `HAVING` clause, you are removing operators where there are no calls. If there were no calls, then `CallDate` would be `NULL`, and `NULL=20170104` is not true, so these rows are excluded. You need to move this predicate to your join clause:

```
SELECT Operators.id, Operators.Nome, Count(Calls.OpId) AS CountCalls
FROM Operators LEFT JOIN Calls ON (Operators.id = Calls.OpId AND Calls.CallDate=20170104)
GROUP BY Calls.CallDate, Operators.id, Operators.Nome;
```

You also don't need to group by `Calls.CallDate`, since you only have one anyway, so you can just use:

```
SELECT Operators.id, Operators.Nome, Count(Calls.OpId) AS CountCalls
FROM Operators LEFT JOIN Calls ON (Operators.id = Calls.OpId AND Calls.CallDate=20170104)
GROUP BY Operators.id, Operators.Nome;
```

As an aside `HAVING` is the wrong operator. `HAVING` is for filtering aggregates, since you are not filtering an aggregate, you should simply use `WHERE`

```
SELECT Operators.id, Operators.Nome, Count(Calls.OpId) AS CountCalls
FROM Operators LEFT JOIN Calls ON Operators.id = Calls.OpId
WHERE Calls.CallDate=20170104
GROUP BY Calls.CallDate, Operators.id, Operators.Nome;
```

You would use `HAVING` if you wanted to fliter on `CountCalls`, e.g if you only wanted operators that had made more than 1 call you might use:

```
SELECT Operators.id, Operators.Nome, Count(Calls.OpId) AS CountCalls
FROM Operators LEFT JOIN Calls ON Operators.id = Calls.OpId
WHERE Calls.CallDate=20170104
GROUP BY Calls.CallDate, Operators.id, Operators.Nome
HAVING Count(Calls.OpId) > 1;
```

This would only return

```
Id Nome CountCalls
--+----+----------
 1 JDOE          2
```

Comment: Just an observation: since these changes are done, MS-Access will refuse to show this query in design mode, it will only be available as SQL or result view. Apparently, its interface can't deal with this more complex Join clause. Shame on MS about this...

Comment: Well, that's true for any atypical join, and I wouldn't shame MS for it. They just can't represent it properly in design view, and there shouldn't be hidden elements to a query that aren't represented there.

Answer (score 2):

Try below query:

```
SELECT o.id, o.name, count(c.opid) as countcalls
FROM Operators o LEFT JOIN calls c ON o.id = c.opid AND c.calldate=20170104
GROUP BY c.calldate, o.id, o.name
ORDER BY o.id;
```

**Output:**

```
+------+------+------------+
| id   | name | countcalls |
+------+------+------------+
|    1 | JDOE |          2 |
|    2 | RROE |          1 |
|    3 | MMOE |          0 |
+------+------+------------+
```