# Rows with 0 value won't appear on Count in SQL query

Tags: sql

I have to get all the posts even if they have 0 likes on the count, but those aren't showing up no matter what, I tried inner join, left outer join and nothing

```
select 
    post.id as idPost, 
    post.data, 
    autor.nome as nome, 
    post.texto, 
    post.idAutor, 
    count(likes.idAutor) as numeroLikes 
from post  
join utilizador autor 
    on autor.id = post.idAutor 
left join likes 
    on post.id = likes.idPost 
left join amigos as a 
    on a.idAmigo2 = post.idAutor   
where (post.idAutor = a.idAmigo2 and a.idAmigo1 = 3) or post.idAutor = 3 
    and idPost > 0 
group by post.id~
```

This is posts table, you can see it's up to ID 43

[image: post table]

and this is the result from the query i posted, you can see it doesn't show the number of likes for idPost 43 because it's 0

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this thread will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793057/how-to-include-zero-0-results-in-count-aggregate

Comment: Your query has many problems.  Please edit the question and show us sample data along with your desired output.

Comment: I posted some images of query results

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your left outer join on `likes` should work when you avoid value comparions attributes of `likes` in the where clause. The comparison forces all rows to have non null values for `likes`in the result. You should modify `idPost > 0` either to `(idPost is null or idPost > 0)` or move this comparison into the approriate join clause.

Comment: thank you, this worked (idPost is null or idPost > 0)

Comment: Do you have values for `idPost` less or equal to 0? If not you can completly remove this comparison.

Comment: I can't because it is needed to stop comments from being refreshes everytime on website and only refresh the new ones as they are created

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query which should not suffer from the problem of posts disappearing because they have no likes:

```
SELECT 
    post.id as idPost,
COUNT(likes.idAutor) AS numeroLikes 
FROM post  
LEFT JOIN utilizador autor 
    ON autor.id = post.idAutor 
LEFT JOIN likes 
    ON post.id = likes.idPost 
LEFT JOIN amigos AS a 
    ON a.idAmigo2 = post.idAutor AND 
       ((post.idAutor = a.idAmigo2 AND a.idAmigo1 = 3) OR
      post.idAutor = 3)
WHERE idPost > 0 
GROUP BY post.id
```

I made three major changes to your query:

- LEFT JOIN from post to utilizador; this alone might already fix the problem
- Move all conditions from the `WHERE` clause into an `ON` clause, which should prevent posts from being dropped.
- Note also that I only select the post ID and the count.  The reason for this is that your current select clause is invalid as it contains non aggregate columns.