# Count left join group by excludes zero in result data

Tags: mysql, sql

According to this [How to include "zero" / "0" results in COUNT aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793057/how-to-include-zero-0-results-in-count-aggregate) I need to left join the tbl_postad table.

Following is my query

This queries shows count of ads in each category.

```
SELECT c.*, count(a.post_id) as item_count 
FROM tbl_category c 
LEFT JOIN tbl_postad a on a.post_maincategory = c.cat_id 
WHERE c.cat_parent=0 AND c.cat_promote = 0 
AND c.selActive = 'Y' AND a.post_delete_status!='Y' AND a.post_cat_status!='N' 
AND a.post_status='Y' AND a.block=0 AND a.post_expiredate >= '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' 
GROUP BY c.cat_name 
ORDER BY c.cat_sort asc
```

If remove query related to post it shows all the categories:

```
 SELECT c.*, count(a.post_id) as item_count 
 FROM tbl_category c 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_postad a on a.post_maincategory=c.cat_id 
 WHERE c.cat_parent=0 AND c.cat_promote = 0 AND c.selActive = 'Y' 
 GROUP BY c.cat_name 
 ORDER BY c.cat_sort asc
```

But if I add query related to posts then it excludes all the categories with post count of zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `left join`, all the conditions on the second table should be in the `on` clause.  Otherwise the non-matches turn the `left join` into an `inner join`.

So, try this:

```
select c.*, count(a.post_id) as item_count
from tbl_category c left join
     tbl_postad a
     on a.post_maincategory = c.cat_id and
        a.post_delete_status <> 'Y' and
        a.post_status = 'Y' and
        a.post_cat_status <> 'N' and
        a.block = 0 and
        a.post_expiredate >= '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' 
where c.cat_parent = 0 and
      c.cat_promote = 0 and
      c.selActive = 'Y' ;
```

Note:  You should learn how to use parameters to pass in values such as the ate, rather than munging the query string.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, now the queries works fine and could you please post some links which shows how to use parameters to pass in values, and I don't know what is ate, searched online but don't find any relevant answers.

Comment: @vSugumar . . . These are called prepared statements.  I don't know what application you are using, but a PHP is typical:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance