# Return 0 total using Grouping Set

Tags: sql, oracle10g

The below query works perfectly when there are rows.
Output as:

```
   Duplicates,2
   Syntax,5
   Total,7
```

However I need to return a row of Total, 0 when there are no rows.

Have tried changing the INNER JOIN to a RIGHT JOIN but this then returns two rows. 
          Total,0
          Total,0

I probably could work with that and strip the extra one in my VB code but would like to work out how to do it within the SQL.

```
    SELECT
       nvl(to_char(dbms_lob.substr(message, 50, 1 )),'Total') AS TYPE ,
       Count(dbms_lob.substr( message, 50, 1 )) AS "HOWMANY"
   FROM applicationlogentries ALE
   INNER JOIN (
            SELECT REFERENCE_ID , Max(entry_date) AS MaxDateTime
            FROM APPLICATIONLOGENTRIES
            where Trunc(entry_date) = Trunc(SYSDATE) -8
            GROUP BY  REFERENCE_ID) groupedAle
            ON ale.reference_id = groupedAle.reference_id
            AND ale.last_updated = groupedAle.MaxDateTime
            AND ale.reference_id IN
                   (SELECT ID FROM documentsin
                    where Trunc(date_received) = Trunc(SYSDATE) -8 AND 
          status = 3)
       group by grouping sets((),(dbms_lob.substr( message, 50, 1 )))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

If you run:

```
select count(*)
from t;
```

Then you will *always* get one row, even if `t` is empty.  That is the definition of an aggregation over the whole table.

If you run:

```
select count(*)
from t
group by <whatever>
```

Then you will get one row per group.  If there are no groups (i.e. no data in the table), you get no rows.

I can think of no way to return a row -- in this case -- on an empty table, using `group by`.

Apparently,

```
group by grouping sets ( () )
```

behaves like the second case and not the first.  It is saying "there is a `group by`, so one row per group" *and* "there is no data so there are no groups".

The only solution I can readily think of is the brute force solution:  `union all` for the total that you want to calculate.

Comment: Hi Gordon, yes I pretty much expected that, but thought i'd give it a shot on here. Will leave it open a couple of days in case someone has a weird and wonderful solution. I have actually coded around it in VB, by saying if the rowcount variable returned is empty then there were no rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a left outer join on your data to get the count of zero to return.  I have found this page that helped me understand how to test this.  I created a couple of dummy tables.   It appears you must have records in one of your joined tables if you expect the count(*) to give you a zero value.

[How to include "zero" / "0" results in COUNT aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793057/how-to-include-zero-0-results-in-count-aggregate)

> "The reason why this is working, is that the outer (left) join will
>   return NULL for those persons that do not have an appointment. The
>   aggregate function count() will not count NULL values and thus you'll
>   get a zero."

```
 Select a.colA, count(b.ColA)

from [dbo].[SRJTestTable1] as a
Join [dbo].[SRJTestTable2] as b
ON a.ColA =  b.ColA
Group by a.ColA
```

Assuming that table 1 has records and table 2 does NOT and you want to count the values from table 2 you will get nothing returned on an inner join.   If you change to a left outer join the result will be a zero.

I have run this with and without the outer join and I did get a count of zero to return with the outer join.

Couldn't get my image to appear in-line.   Here is a quick link to it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1abv6.jpg

Comment: Hi Steven, with LEFT OUTER, I get lots of rows I do not want, had already tried that. Thanks anyway.