# I need to show all cars from BRAND_CAR even if there is no car in it

Tags: mysql, sql, ifnull

I created this query and i can't show all brand car even with 0 vehicule created on vehicule table.

```sql
SELECT BRAND_CAR_NAME, COUNT(*)
FROM brand b, vehicule v, model mo
WHERE v.ID_MODEL = mo.ID_MODEL
AND mo.ID_BRAND = b.ID_BRAND
GROUP BY BRAND_CAR_NAME
```

what it show me :

```
Brand 1 :   1
Brand 3 :   1 
Brand 4 :   1
Brand 6 :   1
```

I want to see :

```
            Brand 1 : 1
            Brand 3 : 1 
            Brand 4 : 1
            Brand 6 : 1
            brand 2 : 0
            brand 5 : 0
            brand 7 : 0
```

```
SELECT NOM_MARQUE, IFNULL(v.ID_VOITURE)
FROM marque m, voiture v, model mo
WHERE v.ID_MODEL = mo.ID_MODEL
AND mo.ID_MARQUE = m.ID_MARQUE
GROUP BY NOM_MARQUE
```

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793057/how-to-include-zero-0-results-in-count-aggregate

Comment: Don't use comma separated joins do read up on LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Use `Left Join` to get the result, try the below query

```
SELECT b.BRAND_CAR_NAME, COUNT(*) 
FROM brand b
LEFT JOIN model mo ON b.ID_BRAND = mo.ID_BRAND
INNER JOIN vehicule v ON mo.ID_MODEL = v.ID_MODEL
GROUP BY b.BRAND_CAR_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` especially just before `vehicule` table with `SUM( IFNULL(SIGN(v.ID_MODEL),0) )`

( *I think even better to use a `LEFT JOIN` before `model` table also, againct missing records for `model` table* )

```
SELECT BRAND_CAR_NAME, SUM( IFNULL(SIGN(v.ID_MODEL),0) ) as BRAND_COUNT
  FROM brand b
  LEFT JOIN model mo ON mo.ID_BRAND = b.ID_BRAND
  LEFT JOIN vehicule v ON v.ID_MODEL = mo.ID_MODEL
 GROUP BY BRAND_CAR_NAME;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1378691cef952a9eb6973560485e59ae)</kbd>

Comment: With SUM i get the ID in BRAND_COUNT, i got 6 vehicule created with 6 distinct brand, in a list of 20 brand. This query show me almost the good result, the only thing is instead of having a count of how many vehicule of each brand is created, i got the value of ID (ex : Fiat has ID 20, and i got Fiat : 20,  Ferrari 18, Ford 10, Mercredes 7, Citreon 5, Peugeot 1, Seat 0, Renaut 0, BMW 0, Wolkwagen 0 ect..

Comment: @Kovenk have a look at the Demo, and tell me what's different with your data model please.

Comment: And when i replace SUM by COUNT i got wrong values. BWM > 3 and all the other > 1. I don't understand why i got those numbers

Comment: @Kovenk well, we need one more function : `SIGN()`

Comment: But with sign, if i got 2 Fiat, it will return 1?

Comment: @Kovenk can I see your tables' structure and sample data, preferably on a fiddle site  ?

Comment: What is a Fiddle site? I have the .sql file but don't know where to share it

Comment: @Kovenk I meant you can create your tables and populate them within a fiddle site like my Demo, and share by a link with us.