# How to show the rest of periods with no data (with group by and count) - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count the records of each period for specific employees. I already removed unnecessary records by using "row_number() over (partition by...", then in the select, above I counted and grouped them to show how many times they exist for a given period number. The output and my SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT TBL.Name, TBL.Period_ID, count(*) as PeriodCount from (
Select row_number() over (partition by TBL1.Period_Id, TBL1.Name, TBL1.Date order by 
TBL1.Period_Id desc) as rn1,  * from ( 

<selected columns>
...
<joins>
...
<where clause>
...

) as TBL1
)as TBL
where TBL.rn1 = 1 

Group by TBL.Name, TBL.Period_ID
order by 1
```

Output:

[image]

But what I actually want is to show all the periods for all users even with 0 as counted values. The desired output should look like:

[image]

I've already tried using the solution with left join

[How to include "zero" / "0" results in COUNT aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793057/how-to-include-zero-0-results-in-count-aggregate)

after ")TBL" section but results stay the same.

Can you help me with this, please? :)

Bart

Answer (score 0):

You need `cross join` :

```
with cte as (
     <your query>
)
select distinct c.name, c1.period_id, coalesce(cc.period_count, 0) as period_count
from cte c cross join
     ( select distinct c1.period_id from cte c1 
     ) c1 left join
     cte cc
     on cc.name = c.name and cc.period_id = c1.period_id;
```

Comment: I've tried your solution now but the results stay the same. There are no data for periods 115, 116 for User3 but I need to show them as 0 then.

Comment: @Alwexistwo . . . This should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You use a `cross join` to general the rows -- all combinations of names and periods.  Then a `left join` to bring in the current information:

```
with cte as (
     <your query>
     )
select n.name, p.period_id, coalesce(cte.period_count, 0) as period_count
from (select distinct name from cte) n cross join
     (select distinct period_id from cte) p left join 
     cte 
     on cte.name = n.name and cte.period_id = p.period_id;
```

This uses `select distinct` to get the desired names and periods.  If you have another source (even a derived table of constants), then that is usually a better choice.

Comment: Do I need to change anything in my query that i just posted above and use your solution? Because sadly the results didnt changed...

Comment: @Alwexistwo. . .  Yes, you need to  put your existing  query inside `cte`.

Comment: I already did that. The results still not showing the 0... Is it because the rows with period number 115 and 116 doesnt exist for user3? But even so, I wanted to show them as 0...