# How can I use count(*) to select from another table with condition and group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on two tables called `Students` and `departments`

**Students**

```
StudentId    |     Name       |    Address    |  DepartmentId

    1        |    Simons      |    Los Angeles|   001
    2        |    Mark        |    Texas      |   001
    3        |    Kelly       |    Florida    |   002
    4        |    Philip      |    New York   |   002
```

**Department**

```
DepartmentId   |     Name       |    Date_Creation

    001        |    Maths       |    01/09/2021
    002        |    Physics     |    01/08/2021
```

What I need exactly is to retrieve all information from Department Table with the number of students that are from the department ( group by ).

**Expected results:**

```
DepartmentId   |     Name        |  NumberOfStudents

    001        |    Maths        |        2 
    002        |    Physics      |        2
```

I have tried to execute the query but it did not give me any result:

```
Select DepartmentId, Name, (select count(*)
from Students s, Departments d
where s.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId) as NumberOfStudents
```

What can I modify to get the needed result?

Comment: FYI, it's 2021, *long* past time you adopted the ANSI-92 Explicit JOIN syntax; it's been about for **29 years**. There's no need to be using that 1980's Implicit JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use either an `APPLY` or a pre-grouped join

```sql
SELECT
  d.Name,
  s.cnt
FROM dept AS d
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM students AS s
    WHERE s.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId
) s;
-- alternatively
SELECT
  d.Name,
  ISNULL(s.cnt, 0) cnt
FROM dept AS d
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT s.DepartmentId, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM students AS s
    GROUP BY s.DepartmentId
) s ON s.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId;
```

Comment: Thank you but what I have 0 as the number of students in one department? how can I display this department?

Comment: OK modified that for you

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface , I have used this solution and it also worked for me . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793057/how-to-include-zero-0-results-in-count-aggregate

Answer (score 2):

maybe?

```
SELECT
  d.Name,
  COUNT(s.StudentId) AS cnt
FROM students AS s
INNER JOIN dept AS d
  ON s.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId
GROUP BY d.Name
```