# Include zero count in groupby

Tags: postgresql

I have this table

```
person  outcome
Peter   positive
Peter   positive
Peter   positive
Eric    positive
Eric    positive
Eric    negative
```

and want to count the number of rows each person has a positive/negative outcome.

```
select person, outcome, count(*)
from public.test123
group by person, outcome

person  outcome count
Peter   positive    3
Eric    positive    2
Eric    negative    1
```

But I also want a zero count for Peter negative. I've seen answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793057/how-to-include-zero-0-results-in-count-aggregate) but I have nothing to join the table to?

How can I groupby, count and include zeros?

```
person  outcome count
Peter   positive    3
Peter   negative    0
Eric    positive    2
Eric    negative    1
```

zxc

```
create table public.test123 (
    person      VARCHAR(20),
    outcome     VARCHAR(20));
    
insert into public.test123(person, outcome)
    VALUES
        ('Peter', 'positive'),
        ('Peter', 'positive'),
        ('Peter', 'positive'),
        ('Eric', 'positive'),
        ('Eric', 'positive'),
        ('Eric', 'negative');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=25f71bff61cdef9775c51b04bc875ef9)

```
SELECT
    s.person,
    s.outcome,
    SUM((t.outcome IS NOT NULL)::int) as cnt                           -- 4
FROM (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM unnest(ARRAY['positive', 'negative']) as x(outcome),          -- 1
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT                                                -- 2
            person
        FROM test123
    ) s
) s
LEFT JOIN test123 t ON t.person = s.person AND t.outcome = s.outcome   -- 3
GROUP BY s.person, s.outcome
```

1. Create a list of all possible outcome values.
2. Join it with all possible person values. Now you have a cartesian table with all possible combinations.
3. This can be used to join your original table.
4. Count all non-`NULL` values for each combination (in that case I uses `SUM()` with all non-`NULL` values == `1`, `0` else)